# Checking of values within Array in c

Tags: c, arrays

How can I search an array to find out whether it contains a set of values 
within the specific range of elements in the array *(may be from position 2 to position 7, the first elements would be start of frame, length etc )*

```
if input_data[1:5] == (45, 35, 230, 28)

if contains 45 
    send sensor 1 data;
if contains 35
    send sensor 2 data;
if contains 230 
    send sensor 3 data;
if contains 28
    send sensor 4 data;
```

It may contain any combinations *(order)* of the above values or doesn't contain any one of the elements and should stop sending data if the associated element is not found

I am trying to send some requested data based on the received elements

Updated   !!

The data is received only once(only when updated), according to the Received data i need to send the requested outgoing data in the background,

```
if input_data[1:5] == (45, 35, 230, 28)
if contains 45 
    send_Sensordata1 = 1

if contains 28
    send_Sensordata4 = 1
```

in other function (running in background)

```
if send_Sensordata1 ==1 
   do something here(main sending stuff goes here)
if send_Sensordata4 ==1 
   do something here (main sending stuff goes here)
```

so in the first incoming data i get all the  elements, then the requested data is sent, but if an element is missing in the next incoming  data i need to stop sending outgoing data for that particular request (like toggle)

Comment: loop and if statements perhaps?

Comment: *...but if an element is missing in the next incoming data...*. Does the array itself gets updated when the next incoming data arrives?

Comment: @ Haris .. yes it gets updated, so if  i get the incoming data as (45,35,230,28)  it wants all the data from all the sensors. Similarly when new incomming data is (45,230) i need to send outgoing data only to those requests and stop the remaining

Comment: Then the code I posted will work, the only thing missing is that you want it to be done in the background. Can you explain a little more about that, do you want it to be done in parallel?

Comment: How do your array looping code and the code which will send data in the background communicate? Do they run in different threads or processes?

Comment: i have  main loop which runs `update_request` and `send_data`. so according to the updated variables in '(update_request)` in the above code the  data is sent from `send_data` i need to turn the variable back to 0 so that the data associated with it is not sent ---- for example --->`void send_data { if send_Sensordata1 == 1 { send 1,2,3,etc.}}}....`

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop over the `array` and look for the those particular elements every time.

```
for(i=2; i<7; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 45) 
        send sensor 1 data;
    else if(array[i] == 35)
        send sensor 2 data;
    else if(array[i] == 230) 
        send sensor 3 data;
    else if(array[i] == 28)
        send sensor 4 data;
}
```

Comment: @ Haris , i was able to run it, but got into other issue, have a look at the updated question

Answer (score 0):

The array loop will start from 1 to get element 2 as in c array start from 0.

```
for(i=1; i<7; i++)
{
    if(array[i] == 45) 
        send sensor 1 data;
    else if(array[i] == 35)
        send sensor 2 data;
    else if(array[i] == 230) 
        send sensor 3 data;
    else if(array[i] == 28)
        send sensor 4 data;
}
```